# any php function to send email without mail()

Tags: php, email

i am using 
mail() function to send email from PHP without any authentication.

This function only work on my web server, but does not work on a local machine.

I am looking for best PHP function to send a email with authentication which would work on any machine without modifying the php.ini

i am using PHP with IIS and windows

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility is to install mail and net_smtp through pear.

```
pear install Mail
pear install Net_Smtp
```

then you have the possibility to send mail with SMTP authentication to another server:

```
require_once "Mail.php";

$body = "Mein Mail Body\n";
$subject = "Mail mit SMTP Authentifizierung";
$mail_to = "zumir@meinemailserver.de";
$mail_from = "phpmailer@meinemailserver.de";

//SMTP Verbindungsdaten
$host = "smtp.meinemailserver.de";
$username = "phpmailer";
$password = "SuperGeheim";

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
 array (
 'host' => $host,
 'auth' => true,
 'username' => $username,
 'password' => $password
));

$headers = array (
 'From' => $mail_from,
 'To' => $mail_to,
 'Subject' => $subject
);
$mail = $smtp->send($mail_to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
 echo "Fehler beim Versender der E-Mail : ". $mail-&gt;getMessage();
}
```

(taken from http://www.jgeppert.com/2009/06/php-e-mail-mit-smtp-authentifizierung-versenden/)

Comment: Another way is to configure the php.ini

Comment: You can install PEAR on Windows aswell:
In your PHP Installation folder should be a batch file named "go-pear.bat"
Use this file to install pear.

Comment: sorry i dont know how to install pear, i have following text in go-pear.bat

@ECHO OFF
set PHP_BIN=php.exe
%PHP_BIN% -d output_buffering=0 PEAR\go-pear.phar
pause

can you tell me how to install it?

Comment: Start cmd.exe and change into your php directory, where go-pear.bat resides.
Then just type "go-pear" and follow the instructions on the screen.

Comment: thanks for your help, i did that after completion i copy & past your code but not working...

Answer (score 1):

You should run a local [smtp server](http://www.softstack.com/freesmtp.html). This will let `mail()` just work as long as that program is running. There are other similar servers that will write mail to a file so no mail actually goes out on the dev enviroment.

`Mail()` is the way to go for sending mail. you just have a config issue locally :D

Comment: I've found it works even without an smtp server... which does seem slightly odd now I think about it!

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a working SMTP server to test in your own box, run this little guy on your box so you can test mail stuff without changing your mail-handling code.

http://www.softstack.com/freesmtp.html (free standalone simple stmp server)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem earlier this week, and found [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). I've only heard good things about it. Worked fine for me.

It can send by SMTP, sendmail, or `mail()`. For local development, you would have to connect to a SMTP server, either one you run locally, or an external.